# How to write a conditional custom loss function for a Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to build a model that can do landmark detection for Dog Faces - if a dog face is present, extract the x/y coordinates of the eyes and the nose, otherwise tell me that there's no dog face.

I would like my output tensor to be of size 7:

- output[0] - be the probability that a dog face is present or not
- output[1]/output[2] - x/y of the left eye
- output[3]/output[4] - x/y of the right eye
- output[5]/output[6] - x/y of the nose

I can't figure out how to write a custom loss function that would go something like this:

```py
# This is largely pseudo-code!
def custom_l1_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  if y_true[0] == 1:
    # Probability that there's a dog face = 1
    return K.sum(K.abs(y_pred[1:] - y_true[1:]), axis=-1)
  else:
    # Only return the difference in probabilities that a dog face is present
    return y_true[0] - y_pred[0]
```

**Question**: Has anybody had experience with writing a similar conditional loss function in Keras?

Answer (score 4):

You can extract column [0] and use it as a mask as shown in the following code, so that your conditional loss calculation is simplified into one line calculation.

```
def custom_l1_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    y_true_present = y_true[...,0:1]
    y_pred_present = y_pred[...,0:1]

    loss = K.sum(y_true_present*K.abs(y_pred[...,1:] - y_true[...,1:]),axis=-1)+ K.sum((1-y_true_present)*K.abs(y_true_present-y_pred_present),axis=-1)

    return loss
```

Comment: Is there any different way that I can use if--elif--else in a custom keras loss function? I'm getting following error while trying. **Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.**